# Postfix/Dovecot - Initial Config - Test Email Results - 554 5.7.1 Client host rejected: Access denied

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I sent an email successfully. Can't say the same for receiving. When I attempt to, I get an email saying that the message was blocked with the following diagnostic code:

Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <mail-qv1-f52.google.com[209.85.219.52]>: Client host rejected: Access denied

Went through the Postfix Configuration wizard again by running 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix'. I commented out smtpd_receipient_restrictions. Ran 'sudo systemctl restart prefix'. Looked at other posts, but they mostly say "Relay access denied", which seems different.

Here is the postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = fullstack.equityentity.com, mail.equityentity.com, equityentity.com, localhost.equityentity.com, localhost
mydomain = equityentity.com
myhostname = fullstack.equityentity.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.equityentity.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.equityentity.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

And the doveconf -n:

```
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.4.0-144-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS ext4
# Hostname: fullstack.equityentity.com
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@equityentity.com
protocols = " imap lmtp pop3"
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.equityentity.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You likely have additional overrides set in master configuration - use `postconf -M` to generate a neatly formatted dump of that file. (About the already shared config: That is the expected `-n` output, merely the headings spell out a different option than apparently used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options and/or references to additional policy daemons/milters in your `master.cf`, and one of those could be denying access. I know your `main.cf` dump does not show out the full picture because it references the non-default service name `policyd-spf`.

Investigate additional overrides (-o option=value) of the port 25 (smtp inet) service.

---

Also investigate why you have the non-default `broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes`. Its not dangerous by itself, but if you need it, you are probably accommodating very unusual clients, which might not mix well with running a mail server open to public internet.

Comment: You are right. I commented out smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject in master.cf and it began working. I'll have to figure out SASL. Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyMallgren you may want to keep SASL disabled (smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no) for port 25 (smtp inet), but mandatory (smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes + smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject) on port 465 (smtps inet) - that way you will have less potential for unintended access/restrictions resulting from trying to serve two very different sorts of clients with a single restriction set.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at that when it is up and running. I hope you'll know I tried to up vote your answer, but I don't have enough experience points.